# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte (problem when using django)

Tags: python, django, encoding, character-encoding

I wrote a simple html parsing class in python and it seems to work fine and then I try to use it with django and I get this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 54465: ordinal not in range(128)
```

which is strange because I added this: `# encoding: utf-8` to the top of my class.  I don't really know much about encoding but can someone perhaps give me an idea of what's going here?  Btw, I also insured that the source html was already in utf-8.  Thanks!

Comment: `# encoding: utf-8` won't do anything to how your class functions. It's just a comment... I think you may be confusing it with putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file, which simply tries to alert the parser (or text editor, etc) of the encoding of the _source code_.

Comment: well, I at least know for sure that it's a django issue and not a python issue.  I try the class in python alone and it works fine.  Then when I try to use it in django it returns an error that would indicate that it interprets everything in ascii.  How can I make django think that everything is in utf-8?  Update:  nevermind I got it.  See my answer below.

Comment: @voithos:  `# encoding: utf-8` and `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` have exactly the same effect. Python uses a regular expression to parse the encoding declaration; see http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, I got it.  All I needed to do was include `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the django view as well and that solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting that line at the top of your file.  According to [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), it has to be in the top two lines.

Comment: You can also follow these instructions to make your encoding universal across all files: http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/32

Comment: Note that this will affect only string literals, not variables.