# Sending UTF-encoded POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘ascii’ codec can’t decode byte (problem when using django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520882/ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-problem-when-using-django)

From a Chrome extension, I try to send a POST request:

```
var = encodeURIComponent(somevariable);

var parameters = "var=" + var;
mypostrequest.open("POST", "django/page/", true);
mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
mypostrequest.send(parameters);
```

and when in `somevariable`, there are some UTF-chars, it breaks with

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 14: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

In Django I have:

```
some_var = form.cleaned_data['var'].replace('\n','')
```

The result is wrong because the `some_var` contains wrong chars:

```
some_var = u"blah blah blah z\u0142o\u017a"
```

Of course, it should be `u"blah blah blah złoź"`, but I really don't know where and how I should change the encoding.

---

**Update after closure:**

This question isn't duplicate - the problem isn't in the message. I googled more than you think you can.

The most important thing (which I don't understand) is the difference between

u"ł" and u"\u0142" and "\u0142"

all of those means **almost** the same, but not the same.

Comment: Avoid ranty titles!

Comment: Rant harder. `>>> print u"blah blah blah z\u0142o\u017a"`
`blah blah blah złoź`

Comment: If you hate unicode.. which encoding do you prefer for.. lets say asian.. languages?

Comment: @micha i hate unicode AND python together ;D

Comment: @SledgehammerPL: So, as pointed out, the string you got is correct. Where does the error come in?

Comment: Well, its not correct - u"\u0142" != u"ł"

Comment: I suppose that "\u0142" == u"ł", but i'm not sure

Comment: [U+0142 LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/142/index.htm)

Comment: The Google search for your error message, even restricted to Stack Overflow, gives 12.5K hits... I guess you haven't done much googling before posting...

Comment: @dda - you don't understand the problem, but you mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you be complaining about Unicode if you don't actually use it?

```
some_var = form.cleaned_data['var'].replace(u'\n', u'')
```

Comment: i don't know what is in form.cleaned_data['var'], but i want to have unicode as type of some_var

Comment: I really don't know why, but it works!!! 8-o

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: i saw it earlier - but unfortunately it doesn't speak to me... I'm still thinking, that some goblins pees sometimes into my code ;D